# Условие if с проверкой списка

Tags: python, if

```
х = input("введите число: ")
y = 1
z = 2
a = 3
q = [(y),(z),(a)]
if x == q :
   print("1")
```

иф не работает

Comment: Что нужно сделать-то, что проверять?

Comment: надо чтоб когда ты вводил в инпуте число от 1 до 3 выводилась цифра 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = int(input("введите число: "))
y = 1
z = 2
a = 3
if x in (y, z, a):
    print('1')
```

Comment: мне именно с переменными надо

Comment: @Станислав так подойдет?

Comment: да подойдет,спасибо

Comment: @Станислав, ну тогда можете принять мой ответ как решение нажав соответствующую кнопку слева от него

Answer (score 0):

`x` вообще-то строка. Её можно привести к целому c помощью `int(input..)`, а затем проверить диапазон или вхождение в список с помощью `in`